# Why is importing enzyme to test a react component throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I just want to use enzyme to test my react components.

Blow is my test code. Do nothing but only import some dependencies.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import List from '../../../src/pages/index/components/List';

describe('List components test', () => {

});
```

When I exec command npm run test, the termial will call error message like this

[image]

I search this problem with google, I find similar problem in github, https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/47, but I have tried everything metion in this issue, it still error all the time( like setting external for webpack)

So, how can I solve this problem?

my dependencies's version is blow

```
"antd-mobile": "^1.0.0",
"classnames": "^2.2.5",
"fastclick": "^1.0.6",
"keymaster": "^1.6.2",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"md5": "^2.2.1",
"rc-progress": "^2.2.2",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.0",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2"
"atool-build": "^1.0.2",
"atool-test": "^0.5.5",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3",
"babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
"babel-plugin-import": "^1.1.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
"clone": "^2.1.0",
"co-mocha": "^1.2.0",
"cross-env": "^3.1.4",
"debug": "^3.0.0",
"dora": "^0.3.3",
"dora-plugin-config-manager": "^0.2.3",
"dora-plugin-livereload": "^0.5.2",
"dora-plugin-simulator": "^0.2.0",
"dora-plugin-webpack": "^0.6.5",
"enzyme": "^2.9.1",
"eslint": "^3.19.0",
"eslint-config-egg": "^3.2.0",
"eslint-config-react-app": "^0.6.2",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.33.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.0",
"lint-staged": "^3.4.0",
"object-assign": "^4.1.1",
"postcss-plugin-px2rem": "^0.6.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
"sinon": "^3.2.1",
"stylelint": "^8.0.0",
"stylelint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
"svg-sprite-loader": "^0.3.0",
"ts-loader": "^2.3.2",
"tslint": "^5.6.0",
"tslint-eslint-rules": "^4.1.1",
"tslint-react": "^3.2.0",
"typescript": "^2.4.2",
"webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
```

Comment: what is your react version?

Comment: my react version is 15.6.1 @mradziwon

Comment: can you update your question with package.json?

Comment: @mradziwon  done

Comment: it isn't your full package.json, show us dependencies and devDependencies.